# ggplot2 in R: adding error bars not working

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data.frame

```
   trend_id stock_name invest_amnt       sd group    ymean       se       ic
1        -1        DUD        3180 2446.932    DU 4970.000 244.6932 512.1487
2        -1        SGD        2630 2204.930    SG 4823.333 220.4930 461.4972
3        -1        SLD        3370 2751.143    SL 5013.333 275.1143 575.8209
4        -1        UDD        2980 2407.816    UD 5273.333 240.7816 503.9616
5         0        DUN        5660 2357.965    DU 4970.000 235.7965 493.5278
6         0        SGN        5400 2490.386    SG 4823.333 249.0386 521.2437
7         0        SLN        5650 2768.419    SL 5013.333 276.8419 579.4367
8         0        UDN        6230 2424.017    UD 5273.333 242.4017 507.3526
9         1        DUU        6070 3248.170    DU 4970.000 324.8170 679.8497
10        1        SGU        6440 3156.907    SG 4823.333 315.6907 660.7482
11        1        SLU        6020 3287.503    SL 5013.333 328.7503 688.0823
12        1        UDU        6610 3011.409    UD 5273.333 301.1409 630.2952
```

I can draw a barplot like this

```
ggplot(data=df.mean, aes(x=stock_name, y=invest_amnt, fill=trend_id)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())+
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired")+
  theme_minimal()
```

However, when I try to add error bars, nothing happens. This is my code

```
ggplot(data=df.mean, aes(x=stock_name, y=invest_amnt, fill=trend_id)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +

  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=invest_amnt-sd, ymax=invest_amnt+sd), width=.2,
                 position=position_dodge(.9))

p + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired") + theme_minimal()
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. First you say "I can draw a barplot with error bars", but the code that follows does not include `geom_errorbar`. In the second code block, you do not assign the result of `ggplot` to the variable `p`; perhaps that is the problem.

Comment: @neilfws Sorry, was a typo. I edited the question.

Comment: Your code works fine - assuming that `trend_id` is a factor, otherwise `scale_fill_brewer` will return an error. It's just that you have not assigned the output to `p` before running the second line `p + ...`.

Comment: You are both correct. Thank you